# Calendar switching in Matlab GUI (DateChooserPanel)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, calendar, switching

I have a question about Matlab GUI's. I'm gonna try and explain as best as I can what exactly I need help for.
I am using GUIDE for building GUI, and have a listbox with ~10 names in it. When I click on each of the names (individuals) a calendar will appear where I can select multiple dates on.
Each person has it's own calendar which appears when you click on their name for the first time. Every calendar is created in the same place(coordinates) on GUI. Calendars become visible (are created) after the listbox selection, at first only listbox is visible on the GUI.

The thing I want to do is to be able to switch between each of these calendars depending on what person's name I click on the listbox. For example, click on 'martin' shows his calendar, click on 'joe' brings his calendar up front etc. So basically, I have ~10 calendars I want to switch between (while the selected dates don't reset with each switch).

I am using Jide's DateChooserPanel which is implemented in Matlab, as it is really easy to use and is just perfect for my needs.
The following code generates a calendar and sets an ability to select multiple dates and works perfect:

```
com.mathworks.mwswing.MJUtilities.initJIDE;

jPanel = com.jidesoft.combobox.DateChooserPanel;
[hPanel,hContainer] = javacomponent(jPanel,[219,66,200,200],gcf);
jModel = hPanel.getSelectionModel;
jModel.setSelectionMode(jModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

And I can get the chosen dates with this line:

```
hPanel.getSelectionModel.getSelectedDates
```

And now I'm stuck because I don't know how to switch between those calendars. I was trying to get their handles and somehow get that person's calendar in front of the others, but I couldn't find a way.

Any advice/help is appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you can use a trick, such as making all calenders invisible before you select the new one?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I was thinking of doing that, but I don't know how would I do that. I am not quite familiar with DateChooserPanel's other options.I was looking at the jidesoft.com for more info, but couldn't find it.